# two-different-sections question about python code

Tags: python, machine-learning

i'm new to python so this is a two-different-sections question... first I don't understand what this code means and whats for the DESCR this supposed to be for description isn't ? and for the split part with values? i don't understand the values

```
datasets = [ds.DESCR.split()[0] for ds in datasets]
clf_name = [str(clf).split('(')[0][:12] for clf in clfs]
```

second when do i use `np.ones` or `np.zeros` i know to generate an array of ones or zeros but what i mean is is when specificly in data science does it require me to initialize an array with ones or zeros?

Comment: Please re-edit your question because it's hard to understand what is the problem here, also it's hard to understand what some piece of code does when you get only two lines to analyze.

Comment: I'm supposed to do a comparison between two algorithms on two datasets to see which one has the best performance on which dataset but the problem is that i don't understand how to split the values ? any ideas

Answer (score 0):

This code is creating two lists using [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).
The `ds.DESCR` and other expressions here can mean anything, depending on the context.

As for your second sub-question, I'd advise to as something more specific. 
If you need ones, you use `np.ones`, if you need zeros, you use `np.zeros`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Np.zeros is great if you for example gradually update your matrix with values. Every entry that is not updated by your algorithm stays zero.

In application this could be a matrix that shows you edges in a picture. You create a matrix of the size of the picture filled with zeros and then go over the picture with an kernel that detects edges. For every edge you detect you increase the value in the matrix at the position of the detected edge.

A matrix or a vector of ones is great to do some matrix multiplications. Assume some vector of shape (n,1) x (1,n) of a Vector filled with ones will expand the vector to a matrix of shape (n,n). This is and similar cases can make a vector/matrix of ones necessary.